# Available Wi-Fi networks not even showing in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

My Ethernet works fine but it is not even showing options of available networks in Wi-Fi (Initially it was working fine).

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`, is as follows:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Also o/p of `sudo modprobe wl` is:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic
```

Also command `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` shows error:

```
Can't create report and wl not found.
```